# Java: Can the if/else statement be used with a 'return true' and a 'return false'

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

```
public boolean ifElseStatement(){

    if(conditions){
       statementBody++;
       return true;
    }
       else
       return false;
```

If the condition is met, will this method return `true`? Or might it return `false` because it the final `return` statement is outside of the `if` body?

I am effectively asking is this correct use of the if/else statement when a boolean value needs to be returned? Or perhaps there is a better or universally preferred way to do this?

To clarify,
I am asking if the if-else statement can be used like this, with two return statements. I have always been told to use only one return statement.

Comment: I think the best way to do this code would be to check the condition, increment `statementBody` if true, then just return the condition, bcz whatever the condition is will be what you are returning.

Comment: can you do like this `if(conditions){statementBody++;}  return conditions;`

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking... maybe some more concrete code would make the question clearer? As of right now, yes, that's a perfectly valid way to use if-else.

Comment: it's more like code review post instead of a question. You should try [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The question doesn't actually go anywhere yet. Please clarify what your intentions are.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about this. New to programming and this site.

Comment: I am asking if the if-else statement can be used like this, with two return statements. I have always been told to use only one return statement.

Comment: @Maitiu The practice of using only one return statement is due to several factors, such as memory management (in C) or alternate code flows (in FORTRAN). Nowadays it's not quite as much as an issue. In Java you can certainly have more than one return statement in a method. See this [excellent Programmers.SE question.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/118703/197053) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the condition is true, it will not be able to hit the return of the `else` statement. Once it hits a return, your code immediately returns to where the `ifElseStatement()` was invoked. [Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Answer (score 1):

The method will return the first return statement reached. If conditions == true, will return true, in other case, will return false.